# Prevent caching of some JS files in HTML. (PhoneGap)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

in a simplify example, I have following HTML page (PhoneGap app on iOS and Android):

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script>
    document.write('../../Documents/data.js?u='+(new Date()).getTime() );
    </script>
    <script src="js/some.js"> </script>
</body>
```

But it's just a hack, and even though it seems to work, I'm sure there should be a better solution to it then this.

Comment: Add a config override on that particular file in the webserver's configuration so it's output with no-cache headers. But otherwise the random query string is the usual method for doing this as it's the least intrusive and works universally.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the app cache to signal that date.js needs to be loaded via the network each and every time.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Answer (score 0):

This "WorkAround" works fine.
Following the same workaround.... if you want "clear cache" when you want, set version manually.

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    ...
  <script>
     document.write('../../Documents/data.js?u=001');    //Fixed version
  </script>
<script src="js/some.js"> </script>
```